# codeigniter how to set route with no segment and also no of segment

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, segment

I am stuck with route.
   Here is my route.

```
$route['login_register'] = 'welcome/login_register';
```

First time I don't want to pass any extra segment.
   After Login fail,I want to redirect `login_register` function with failure    argument in URL.
  If I don't use `/(:any)`,I can't access.

```
$this->uri->segment(2);
```

If i use `/(:any)`,it is giving me error when first time redirecting.

```
$route['login_register/(:any)'] = 'welcome/login_register';
```

Answer (score 2):

you cant do `login_register` and `login_register/(:any)` with same route. You can do one more thing with this.

Use one route

```
$route['login_register'] = 'welcome/login_register';
```

then inside function

```
public function login_register($value)
{
    if (empty($value)) { # first method
        echo "No argument passing";
    }
    else{ # second method
        echo "argument is there";;
    }
}
```

So when use passing data to controller send with `/` key. Ex:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>login_register"> This print first method</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>login_register/25"> This print second method</a>
```

Comment: I suggest u to use public function login_register($value ="") in default.